# Why is factory method not necessary when "instantiation takes place in an operation that subclasses can easily override"?

Tags: design-patterns, factory-method

From Design Patterns by Gamma et al,

> Factory Method makes a design more customizable and only a little more
>   complicated. **Other design patterns require new classes**, whereas
>   Factory Method only requires a new operation. People often use Factory
>   Method as the standard way to create objects, but it isn't necessary
>   **when the class that's instantiated never changes** or **when instantiation
>   takes place in an operation that subclasses can easily override, such
>   as an initialization operation**.

1. "Other design patterns" include abstract factory, builder and prototype. Isn't it that prototype does not require new classes either, just like factory method? Or do I misunderstand what "require new classes" means?
2. What does it mean by "when instantiation takes place in an operation that subclasses can easily override, such as an initialization operation"? Why is factory method not necessary in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Let me start by giving a java implementation of the factory method pattern:

```
interface Product {
}

class ConcreteProduct implements Product {
}

abstract class Creator {

    abstract Product createProduct();

    final void usage() {
        final Product product = createProduct();
        System.out.println(product);
    }
}

final class ConcreteCreator extends Creator {

    @Override
    Product createProduct() {
        return new ConcreteProduct();
    }
}
```

1) For the first question, let's examine the sentence

> Other design patterns require new classes, whereas Factory Method only requires a new operation.

Given a new implementation of `Product`, the factory method pattern requires a new subclass, so that can not be the case the sentence is talking about. Instead, the context here is probably that a new dependency to e.g. an `interface Item` is required in the `Creator.usage` method. In this case, no new classes are required, we simply add a `abstract Item createItem()` method to the existing Creator and its subclasses.

Compare this to the prototype pattern. First, lets modify the example code so that the prototype pattern can apply:

```
interface ProductPrototype extends Product {

    ProductPrototype prototypeCopy();
}

class ConcreteProductPrototype implements ProductPrototype, Product {

    @Override
    public ProductPrototype prototypeCopy() {
        return new ConcreteProductPrototype();
    }
}

abstract class Creator {

    final static boolean usePrototype = false;

    abstract Product createProduct();

    final void usage(final ProductPrototype prototype) {
        final Product product;

        if (usePrototype) {
            product = prototype.prototypeCopy();
        } else {
            product = createProduct();
        }

        System.out.println(product);
    }
}
```

Now, if a new `Item` is added which we want to use in our creator, we also need to add new classes `ItemPrototype` and a subclass for each concrete `Item` implementation.

2) For the second question

> People often use Factory Method as the standard way to create objects, but it isn't necessary when [...] instantiation takes place in an operation that subclasses can easily override, such as an initialization operation.

let's look at the example code:

```
interface Product {
}

class ConcreteProduct implements Product {
}

class DefaultProduct implements Product {
}

abstract class Creator {

    Product product;

    void initialize() {
        product = new DefaultProduct();
    }
}

final class ConcreteCreator extends Creator {

    @Override
    void initialize() {
        product = new ConcreteProduct();
    }
}
```

The factory method is not required, because the method is (easily) overriden in the subclass. Note that in the initial example, the factory method is required because we do not want to override the `usage` method in every subclass (i.e. it can *not* be easily overriden).